# Organizar testes no GitHub, boa pratica?

Tags: github, testes

Atualmente estou fazendo uma **pesquisa** para *automizar* e organizar os **testes de um software**.

Em meio as pesquisas *encontrei* algumas *ferramentas*, porém acredito que uma nova ferramenta não seria tão produtivo pois os desenvolvedores teríam quer se familiarizar com a mesma.

*Porém*, por não querer ter mais uma ferramenta de trabalho, pensei em *organizar* os *requerimentos do sistema* no **GitHub** e fazer todos os reports de test por lá. Organizando também em **tags**, como por exemplo, *em teste, aprovado, reprovado e afins*.

Isso é considerado uma **boa prática** para testes? Ou realmente é **necessário** outra ferramenta?

Comment: O que você quer é armazenar o resultado dos testes no Git, é isso? Mas você vai usar uma ferramenta para testes, certo? Teste de unidade, automatizados, aceitação, ...

Comment: @egomesbrandao Exato! O Git seria para armazenar os resultados e o feedback sobre os reports

Comment: Não acho que faça muito sentido a afirmação de que "uma nova ferramenta não seria tão produtivo..."; entenda que o Git é uma ferramenta de gestão de código fonte. Se você tiver PO's que queiram acessar o resultado desses testes, ele deveriam saber Git para isso, o que não faz muito sentido, concorda?
Qual a sua plataforma de desenvolvimento? Linguagem? Além do Git, você usa mais o que? Para eu te dar uma resposta melhor